# Search and replace with shell script

Tags: bash, shell, sed, awk

I need a shell script to find and replace text that would go like:

```
For each line in a file
  find equation mark "="
  remove everything up to the equation mark on that line and replace it with the string cuts[Counter] where Counter counts how many times such substitutions have been made.
```

Could anybody help me out with getting started with a script like that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you mean "up to the **first** equation mark..." and you want to keep the =, this should do it:

```
awk '{c += sub(/[^=]+=/,"cuts["c+0"]=") }1' file
```

Answer (score 1):

In pure bash:

```
counts=0
while IFS= read -r line; do
    if [[ "$line" =~ "=" ]]; then
        echo "${counts}${line#*=}"
        counts=$((counts+1))
    fi
done <infile
```

Note that this will exclude the '='. You can reinclude it in the ehco statement if necessary.

Comment: Note that this will corrupt your output if the file contains backslashes or lines that start or end with blanks or contain chains of blanks or tabs. Always use `while IFS= read -r line` and always quote your variables unless you have very specific reasons not to.

Comment: Edited to quote the variable. I don't see why IFS needs to be changed in this instance?

Comment: @cmh: without setting IFS to a null string your script will strip off leading or trailing blanks from the input file and without using the -r arg for read your script will interpret "\"s and not reproduce them in the output. Try it on a file containing the line `<literal tab>foobar\<end of line>`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the perl one liner for that:

```
perl -plne 'if($.==1){$count=1}if(/=/){$_=~s/[^\=]*[=]/cut[$count]/g;$count++}' temp
```